# What would be the T-SQL syntax to extract these specific values from an nvarchar column in a Table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nvarchar

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have a table (t1) which has a column (`nvarchar` type) called Rank.

An extract of the column is given below:

```
Rank
#1 of 200 lodges in France
#2 of 200 lodges in France
...
#175 of 200 lodges in France
```

I would like to write a SELECT statement which will give me the following output:

```
     Rank                       Rank2        Type      Country
   #1 of 200 lodges in France     1         lodges      France
   #2 of 200 lodges in France     2         lodges      France
   #175 of 200 lodges in France   175       lodges      France
   ...
```

I have tried working with the solution provided here but I am stuck at converting it to meet my requirements:[Extract data between delimeter in Nvarchar field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175666/extract-data-between-delimeter-in-nvarchar-field)

How can I do this using T-SQL?

Comment: A couple of calls to `CHAR_INDEX` should do it. But seriously, it should be done by a scripting language.

Comment: That's bad. You need to normalize the data during the `INSERT` - otherwise you may end up with bad performance implementing this split in the T-SQL. Also, do you have guarantee that tomorrow  invalid record will be inserted (record that does not follow your initial syntax)?

Comment: @gotqn thanks but this record is entered ‘as is’ from the source and we don’t have any control regarding its structure!

Answer (score 0):

What you is string splitter function, SQL2016 has one in built but for previous versions of SQL you can use this [one](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) by Jeff Moden

Here's one way to solve you problem,  This uses the string splitter and conditional aggregation

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE ([Rank] NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @t1 ([Rank])
VALUES ('#1 of 200 lodges in France'), ('#2 of 200 lodges in France'), ('#175 of 200 lodges in France')

SELECT 
     T.[Rank]
    ,Rank2      = MAX(CASE WHEN S.ItemNumber = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT,S.[Item]) END)
    ,[Type]     = MAX(CASE WHEN S.ItemNumber = 4 THEN S.[Item] END)
    ,[Country]  = MAX(CASE WHEN S.ItemNumber = 6 THEN S.[Item] END)
FROM
    @t1 T
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(REPLACE(T.[Rank], '#', ''), ' ') S
GROUP BY
     T.[Rank]
ORDER BY
    Rank2
```

However, there are limitations with this approach as the assumption is that the `Type` and `Country` are only one words

Comment: And what if instead of `lodges` the OP has `sea lodges`?

Comment: true but I can only go by the sample data provided